# Image Magick++ close .display() Popup window by command

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

in documentation of Magick++ I found the command to display an image

```
Image temp_image(my_image);temp_image.display(); // display 'my_image' in a pop-up window
```

this works quite well, but I can find a command to close this window by code.

My goal is to open a window with the image, give image new name by commandline input, then automatically close the window, and show next image to rename.

Although the new popup-window sets the "active window" to it's self.
For entering some input to command line (e.g. new_name), I have to click again at the terminal window.

My (pseudo)code at the moment:

`for(all_images){temp_image.display(); renaming_method();}`

just now I have to close the upcoming window manualy by hand, better would be something like

`for(all_images){temp_image.display(); renaming_method(); temp_image.display_close();}`

do you have any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magick++, and ImageMagick, doesn't have any methods to manage active display windows. You can roll your own XWindow method, but most projects I've seen just do the following routine...

- Write temporary image
- Ask OS to open temporary file by forking a process & calling `xdg-open`, `open`, or `start` commands (depending on OS).
- Send `SIGINT` to **pid** when user wishes to close child process.
- Clean-up any resources

Not ideal, but will get you roughly there.

Comment: thank you! that's helpfull! You have an idea for a good point to start, learning something about this topic?